# Advantages of breaking down a logistic regression in multiple steps?

Tags: regression, logistic

I am wondering what are the advantages/disadvantages of breaking down a logistic regression in multiple steps, when they are available.

Let me explain what I mean by *multiple steps*: Think of it like the customer journey: A cold lead (`A`) becomes a prospect (`B`) who then becomes a customer (`C`).

`A -> B -> C`

I'm interested in predicting the conversion from `A` to `C`, which can be done with a logistic regression.

I wonder if I could also do two logistic regressions, first from `A` to `B`, then from `B` to `C`, and multiply the predictions.

**What are the differences between the two approaches?**

Things to consider:

- What if the conversion rate from `A` to `B` is small? (Then the sample size for the 2nd model is small as well)
- Where does most of the signal come from? Maybe my explanatory variables explain most of `A` to `B` but nothing of `B` to `C`, or the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a sequential logit to me. You can compute a "total" effect of explanatory variables on the finale outcome and decompose that into a weighted sum of the effect of that explanatory variable on each step/transition. See: http://dx.doi.org/10.1177/0049124115591014

Comment: Also take a look at state transition models.